# Writing a function in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm querying the DB and need to parse one of the fields for specific values (using string functions). So I figured it'd be best to write a function for it. I've never written a function before in plsql, so I decided to look at some examples.

I got a copy of a simple "square" function which takes a number and returns the square of it, but am not sure how to call it from the SQL statement.

I only have read access. Will I be able to write functions and use them to retrieve the data I need? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to create a function your user needs the CREATE PROCEDURE privilege granted to it by the DBA:

```
grant create procedure to myschema;
```

If you have the privilege then you can create a function like this

```
create function square(n in number) return number
is
  return n*n;
end;
```

And you can call it from SQL like this:

```
select num, square(num)
from mytable;
```

Note: in Oracle it is usually preferred to create functions in [packages](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/packages.htm#CIHIJECJ), in which case the calling SQL would be like:

```
select num, mypackage.square(num)
from mytable;
```

Comment: Hmm so I will need more privileges for that. Guess I will have to make do with what I have.